# undefined method `account' for Twilio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using twilio and get: error undefined method `account' for Twilio.

```
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new('twilio_sid','twilio_token')
    # Create and send an SMS message
    client.account.sms.messages.create(
    from: "+12345678901",
    to: user.contact,
    body: "Thanks for signing up. To verify your account, please reply HELLO to this message."
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed `api` in your chain of calls. Try this:

```
client.api.account.messages.create(
  from: "+12345678901",
  to: user.contact,
  body: "Thanks for signing up. To verify your account, please reply HELLO to 
  this message."
)
```

Comment: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/wiki/Ruby-Version-5.x-Upgrade-Guide

Answer (score 2):

Would recommend reviewing Twilio's documentation here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-send-sms-messages-in-ruby

There have been some changes with Ruby Helper Library 5.x. (Note that the old version 4.x will only be supported until 10/15/17 - see deprecation notice.)

With 5.x, SMS can be sent as follows:

```
# set up a client to talk to the Twilio REST API
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, auth_token)

@message = @client.messages.create(
  from: '+15017250604',
  to: '+15558675309',
  body: 'This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?'
)
```

My use of this approach has worked so far with twilio-ruby gem v5.2.1.

Comment: reading documentation is overrated by developers, usually not helpful!

Answer (score 0):

should be:

```
client.api.account.messages.create
```